# PHP MSSQL ALIASES

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, aliases

I have to use all this and display all of them

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 263, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS strength
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 265, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS wisdom
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 267, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS dexterity
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 269, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS charisma
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 271, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS intelligence
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 273, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS constitution
```

This is my PHP code so far,
I tried adding another SQL query with the same variable $result so it can also be used on the fetch for $results, but I'm not getting any though.

```
// USING TOP for TEST
$SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 263, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS strength";

// Execute query:
$result = mssql_query($SQL) 
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
    echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
       <th>STR</th>
       <th>WIS</th>
       <th>DEX</th>
       <th>CHA</th>
       <th>INT</th>
       <th>CON</th>
     </tr>";

// Fetch rows:
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['strength'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['wisdom'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['dexterity'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['charisma'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['intelligence'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['constitution'] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";  
    }
```

Any advice, solution? I'm new at this. Thank you.

------------------------------------------------EDIT:
Anyways, how do I sort like this?

```
SELECT CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 263, 2)) as BINARY(2))) FROM CHAR_DATA0 AS strength SORT BY char_key WHERE CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1))=0x00 AS permission
```

Comment: this looks really wrong btw...
$result = mssql_query($SQL) 
    or die('A error occured: ' . mysql_error());
also for nitpicking, die(error) is a lame way to handle errors :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing 6 different sql queries atm. So you'd have to do 6 `mysql_query` and `mysql_fetch_assoc` in your code.
Just do a single query:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 263, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS strength,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 265, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS wisdom,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 267, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS dexterity,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 269, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS charisma,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 271, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS intelligence,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 273, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS constitution
FROM CHAR_DATA0
```

Comment: Hello, I just added 1 more question. Please advice. :)